# Bluetooth Dongle Connection "Failed to open an RFCOMM serial channel" on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth

I tried to setup another computer with a Bluetooth dongle to connect my Macbook Pro (OS X Mavericks). I managed to pair them and ever since then I get these messages every 10-30 seconds and often they crash and freeze the BT:

> **A bluetooth serial failure has occurred.**
>   Failed to open an RFCOMM serial channel.
>   Check if authentication needs to be enabled in your device.

I removed the offending Bluetooth dongle from the favourites and deleted the com.apple.bluetooth.plist file, yet the dongle keeps trying to connect and the error messages keep popping up.

How can I block that dongle from connecting?

[image: Error dialog]

Comment: Any luck? I have a similar problem. I'm trying to read the serial port for the paired device. Starting a screen session on the port results into this error for me.

Comment: Same issue 6 years later.